# VBS - How to check if a word is existing in a registry Data, and then delete it?

Tags: vbscript, registry, registrykey

I must have a vbs script which can delete the string ",vmhgfs" (the coma is important) if it exists in the a registry data.

The registry key is:
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\Order"

The registry value is "ProviderOrder" (it's a string value)

The data is something like  "PICAClientNetwork,SnacNp,vmhgfs,RDPNP,LanmanWorkstation,webclient,PnSson"   but can be very different from a computer to another.

The script must check if the string ",vmhgfs" exists in this data, and if it exists, delete it. If it don't exist, just end.

I'm newbie in VBS, and I've begun to write this script:

```
    Dim objShell, RegValue, RegData
    RegValue = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\Order\ProviderOrder"
    set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    RegData = objShell.RegRead(RegKey)
    wscript.echo RegData
```

The returned echo show me i'm in the right way... but not enough skill to go further...
Can you please help me by finishing it ! Many thanks in advance !

EDIT (before applying your advices):

Hi, thanks guys so I've written the script:

```
Dim objShell, RegValue, RegData, NewRegData
RegValue = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\Order\ProviderOrder"
set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
RegData = objShell.RegRead(RegValue)

if Instr(RegData,",vmhgfs") > 0 then
NewRegData = Replace(RegData,",vmhgfs", "")
objshell.Regwrite RegValue ,NewRegData
    Else IF Instr(RegData,"vmhgfs") > 0 then
    NewRegData2 = Replace(RegData,"vmhgfs,", "")
    objshell.Regwrite RegValue ,NewRegData2
End If
set objshell = nothing
```

The first "IF" is to manage the case where ",vmhgfs" is in the middle of the string. OK The second "IF" is to manage the case where "vmhgfs" is at the beginning of the string

BUT THIS DOESN'T WORK IF ",vmhgfs" IS AT THE VERY END OF THE STRING !!!

I don't undestand that, please help !

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
if InStr(1,RegData,",vmhgfs") > 0 then
NewRegData = left(RegData,InStr(1,RegData,",vmhgfs")) & right(RegData,7+InStr(1,RegData,",vmhgfs"))
```

or (as per Ansgar :) )

```
if InStr(1,RegData,",vmhgfs") > 0 then
newRegData = Replace(RegData, ",vmhgfs", "")
```

Then you just have to write it back to the registry

Comment: Simply use `Replace` instead of fiddling around with string operations: `newRegData = Replace(RegData, ",vmhgfs", "")`

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a regular expression instead of `InStr` here, because the latter would also (mis)detect things like `,vmhgfsFOOBAR`.

```
Set sh = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set re = New RegExp
re.Global = True

val = "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\Order\ProviderOrder"

re.Pattern = "(^|,)vmhgfs(,|$)"
data = re.Replace(sh.RegRead(val), ",")
re.Pattern = "^,|,$"
sh.RegWrite val, re.Replace(data, ""), "REG_SZ"
```